# Proving decidability of $(\mathbb N, +)$ with Quantifier elimination and evaluating basic formulas

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, decidability

The original proof of the decidability of Presburger arithmetic goes by Quantifier elimination, for example noting that
$$
 \exists x (\underbrace{x + \ldots + x}_{\alpha\mbox{ times}} + b = c )
$$
is equivalent with $b \equiv c \pmod{\alpha}$, and such a congruence statement is easily decidable. The proof reduces every formula to a boolean combination of such basic formulas.

Surely, by this reasoning I see that
$$
 \mbox{Th}(\mathbb N) := \{ \varphi \mid \mathbb N \models \varphi \}
$$
is a decidable theory, i.e. for every formula with summation I can decide if it holds or not when interpreted in the natural numbers.

But what Presburger actually is doing, is he gives a decidable set of axioms, considers the closure under deduction of these axioms. And uses the above arguments to conclude that set of all deducable formulas from the axioms is decidable.

But what I do not understand about this reasoning is that if I denote the set of  axioms by $\Delta$, then by soundness
$$
 \{ \varphi \mid \Delta \vdash \varphi \} 
 \subseteq \mbox{Th}(\mathbb N).
$$
But why should these sets be equal? To be more specific, given a formula $\varphi$, reduce it to a formula which is simply decidable over $\mathbb N$, then that it is fullfilled over $\mathbb N$ does not has to imply that $\Delta \vdash \varphi$ holds?

**EDIT**: A translation of Presburgers article could be obtained [here](https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/papers/presburger.pdf). In the introduction of the translator it is said that

> A disjunt consisting of an equation
>   $$
>  \exists x (\alpha x + a = b) \mapsto a \equiv_{\alpha} b
> $$
>   is really the definition of congruence. It appears to be cheating to eliminite a quantifier by forming a congruence, but it is computationally easy to determine if two numbers are congruent.

The problematic parts is "computationally easy to determine". Surely it is easy, but does it imply provability in the axiomatic system?

Comment: How do you write '$\exists x (ax+b=c)$' in Presburger arithmetic? This isn't just (I hope) a trivial nitpick; Presburger arithmetic gets its decidability in the first place from not having sufficient expressive power to talk about multiplication (which is what leads you down these dark paths)...

Comment: This is shorthand notation, meaning $x$ added $a$ times for a fixed $a$ (this is not a variable in the formula, in the original paper it is denoted by $\alpha$). I will edit my thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the quantifier elimination proves is that the axiomatic theory $\Delta$ is *complete*: For every sentence $\varphi$, eliminating the quantifiers eventually produces one of
$$ \Delta \vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow\bot \qquad\text{or}\qquad
\Delta \vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow\top $$

Now suppose $\varphi$ is in $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb N,{+})$. Since we're assuming that all the axioms are true in $\mathbb N$ and the logic is sound, this means that $\Delta\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\bot$ cannot be the case. But then $\Delta\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\top$ must be true. And that is just a few steps away from $\Delta\vdash\varphi$.

---

*Edit:* After a discussion in the comments, the crucial step seems to be that every formula of the shape $\exists x(\alpha x+b=c)$, where $b$ and $c$ are numerals, is either provable or disprovable.

If the formula is *true* in $\mathbb N$, then of course it is provable -- just insert the numeral for the $x$ that works and evaluate it.

If the formula is *false* in $\mathbb N$, then we can still just wing it. Prove by induction that
$$\tag{*} \forall x(x =0 \lor x=1 \lor x=2 \lor \cdots \lor x=c \lor x>c)$$
Then prove
$$\forall x(x>c \to \alpha x + b \ne c) $$
(assuming that $\alpha\ne 0$)
and you can now do a case analysis on (*) to show that no $x$ makes $\alpha x + b = c$ true, by evaluating the left-hand side for each possible $x$ that's not known to be too large.

Comment: My questions concerns the reduction $$ \Delta \vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \bot \quad\mbox{or}\quad \Delta \vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \top $$ where he seems to evaluate parts of the formula (the quantifier-free ones) over $\mathbb N$, which is algorithmically simple, but this does not gives provability in the axiomatic system. He uses this particular model, instead of showing provability. I hope I have stated clearly where my problem is.

Comment: I added a paragraph with a link to the article, and also spelled out more clearly the problematic part.

Comment: @StefanH: A quantifier-free sentence has no variables in it anywhere. The axioms for Presburger arithmetic include the recursion equations for $+$, and that is enough to prove every true (in $\mathbb N$) formula of the form $m+n=k$ where $m,n,k$ are numerals. Presburger arithmetic also proves that different numerals are unequal, so all in all every variable-free atomic formula is either provable or disprovable. And from there is is just propositional logic.

Comment: Okay, I get this. But does this also apply to the "hidden quantifier" in these congrunece relations?

Comment: @StefanH: Edited answer; does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you!